# Very low throughput by using JdbcIO on Google Dataflow

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'd like to load data into Google CloudSQL instance via Google Dataflow.
I think that there're no built-in Sink for CloudSQL, I decide to use org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO.
But, the throughput into CloudSQL is very low (about 6 records/sec).

I suspect that the spec of CloudSQL is too poor, But there's no improve when it's upgraded.

In the log of Dataflow, there're many logs as below:

```
Proposing dynamic split of work unit my-project;2017-06-27_02_58_19-14077185378147382467;6703504927792172410 at 
{"fractionConsumed":0.9669782519340515} 

Rejecting split request because custom reader returned null residual source.
```

What's happened? And How can I improve the performance?

Answer (score 1):

It's resolved!

At generating connection-string, adding as below:

```
JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://google/mydatabase?cloudSqlInstance=myproject:region:instance-name&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&rewriteBatchedStatements=true")
```

Adding "rewriteBatchedStatements=true", it's worked.
The throughput improved to 2000/sec about!

Notice: it workes only when using mysql, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

> Rejecting split request because custom reader returned null residual
>   source.

Whatever custom source you implemented doesn't appear to support dynamic rebalancing.

> I suspect that the spec of CloudSQL is too poor, But there's no
>   improve when it's upgraded.

Are you sure it's throughput to Cloud SQL that is the issue. Have you measured the performance of your source and proven it is the bottleneck?

> I'd like to load data into Google CloudSQL instance via Google
>   Dataflow

Generally, I wouldn't recommend this. Cloud SQL is a single machine database, so I suspect you don't get a lot of benefit, and perhaps it's even a performance negative, by using a horizontally scalable method like Dataflow. You should be able to do ingestion into Cloud SQL just as fast using a single VM instance to load the data.